# Does this infinite trigonometric series converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left|\frac{\cos(3n)}{5^n-1}\right|$$

I think this might need multiple tests to be solved, but I'm not sure. I tried an integral test to no avail. I feel like the integral test might be the only way to do this, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Hint: the terms are less than $\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: $|\cos(3n)|$ is not greater than 1

Answer (score 1):

$$|\cos3n|\le1\implies\left|\frac{\cos3n}{5^n-1}\right|\le\frac1{5^n-1}$$

Comment: Hi, my friend ! How are you doing in these terrible times ? Take care. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$5^n-1=$$
$$(5-1)(5^{n-1}+5^{n-2}+...+5+1)$$

$$\implies$$

$$|\frac{\cos(3n)}{5^n-1}| \le \frac{5}{4}\frac{1}{5^{n}}$$

Use comparison with a geometric seried.